# How to color some percent of a layout?

Tags: android

I want to color e.g. 20 percent of layout background and after some time color 40 percent of it and so on.
How can I achieve this in android ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can start off with a [`ClipDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip). This will clip another drawable — for instance, a `ShapeDrawable` — based on the drawable *level*.

Then in your timer callback:

```
    int level; // from 0 to 10000 = 100%

    view.getBackground.setLevel(level);
```

[Drawable#setLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setLevel(int))

---

EDIT: Here's an example:

1. Define the shape drawable in `/res/drawable`. Call it `bkgd_shape.xml`.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@color/background"/>
   </shape>
   ```
2. Define the background drawable in `/res/drawable`.  Let's call it `bkgd_level.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <clip
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bkgd_shape"
       android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="left|clip_horizontal|fill_vertical"/>
   ```

   You *might* be able to put a color in directly for the drawable source, but I haven't tried it.
3. Set it as the background of your layout:

   ```
       android:background="@drawable/bkgd_level"
   ```
4. Call `setLevel` on the drawable:

   ```
       int level; // from 0 to 10000 = 100%

       view.getBackground.setLevel(level);
   ```

Comment: Updated answer with example XML.

Comment: You are awesome..@krislarson

Answer (score 1):

You can put any type of view in the background and update it's with and set the color you'd like it to have dynamically.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Expanding across the width then, just go by percentage.

```
int percentChange = .2; //Update this accordingly, put in its own function possibly
int backgroundWidth = width * percentChange;
```

For example, using an imageView in the background:

```
ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expandingBackground);
background.requestLayout();
background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;
```

Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: I want to change background color of my activity layout, and in this case, I think my views will not be visible. Am I right ?

Comment: They will be visible, just put it in the background behind everything else. For example, in the component tree inside the relative layout, put it at the bottom (possibly top) of everything, that will move it to the background.