# Flutter - How to color some percent of Card widget?

Tags: flutter

I want to color e.g. 20 percent of a card and change it dynamically. How can I achieve this in Flutter?

I have an idea to achieve this in Android Studio, but I want to achieve it in Flutter.

In Android Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39107045

Answer (score 1):

you can use the LinearGradient

```
  ...,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      stops: const [
        0.5, // percentage value 0.5 = 50%
        0.01,
      ], 
      colors: [
        Colors.red, // the color you need to fill,
        Colors.white, //container base color
      ],
    ),
  ),
  ...,
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your colored widget (which indicates progress) inside a [`FractionallySizedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html)

The widget allows you to resize the width/height of the child inside it by a fractional factor. (It's `widthFactor` in your case)

Comment: In my case, FractionallySizedBox won't help, because I have already a designed Card widget I want just to set its background-color level (percentage).

Comment: If it means coloring your card according to the percentage (Red - 0, Green - 100), you'd have to do that manually, by writing a convenience method/data structure

Comment: I want something similar to Android Studio you get the background then you set the level. like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39107045